# What is the name of the Technic pieces that snap together to make a track?

Tags: technic, part-identification

We have these little black Technic pieces that connect together; they make a track that fits over the gears (sort of like wheeled-belt-track on excavators or tank track).

Can you tell me the name of these pieces? The kids love them, I'm hoping to buy more in the Pick a Brick.

Answer (score 7):

There are three types of chain/track that are similar to what you describe, none of which are currently available through the official Pick A Brick, though all are fairly common on BrickLink.

- The smallest is the [Technic, Link Chain](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3711)
- The medium sized is the [Technic, Link Tread](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3873)
- The largest is the [Technic, Link Tread Wide with Two Pin Holes](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=57518)

There are also several belt styled tracks that might fit your description, but it sounded more like you were referring to the modular parts.